# Pandas Dataframe Filter contains('.'), Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe which contains Year from 1947-2019, but one row contains '2018.1'.
When I filter for Data where Date contains ".", results gives all the Data

```
DataAll.loc[DataAll['Date'].astype(str).str.contains('.'), 'Date']
```

I have checked for Data Types and all are in string

```
DataAll['Date'].apply(type).unique()
array([<class 'str'>], dtype=object)
```

How to filter Data which contains ".", Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is `.` special regex chcaracter, so need `regex=False` or escape it:

```
DataAll.loc[DataAll['Date'].astype(str).str.contains('.', regex=False), 'Date']
```

---

```
DataAll.loc[DataAll['Date'].astype(str).str.contains('\.'), 'Date']
```